# similar concurrent tasks, very different running time (Java)

Tags: java, oracle, jdbc, concurrency

I have an job to insert 8 millions rows into an oracle database table. I scaled out the job onto the 8 cores of the CPU, here is the sample code:

```
final long start = System.currentTimeMillis();
final int batchSize = 800000;
final int nCore = Runtime.getRuntime().availableProcessors();
final int batchPerCore = batchSize / nCore;
final CountDownLatch taskCountDown = new CountDownLatch(nCore);
final CountDownLatch kickoffLatch = new CountDownLatch(1);
final ExecutorService es = Executors.newFixedThreadPool(nCore);

Class.forName("oracle.jdbc.driver.OracleDriver");

for (int n = 0; n < nCore; n++) {

    es.submit(() -> {

        log.info("Thread {} starts working on {} insertion jobs.", Thread.currentThread().getName(), batchPerCore);
        try (Connection conn = DriverManager.getConnection(DB_URL, USER_NAME, PASSWORD)) {

            Assert.assertNotNull("connection established", conn);
            conn.setAutoCommit(false);
            PreparedStatement pstmt = conn.prepareStatement(PREP_STATEMENT);


            for (int i = 0; i < batchPerCore; i++) {
                initPrepTranStatement(pstmt);
                pstmt.addBatch();

            }

            int[] resultTran = pstmt.executeBatch();
            Assert.assertEquals(resultTran.length, batchPerCore);
            conn.commit();
            log.info("Thread {} completed its job!", Thread.currentThread().getName());
            taskCountDown.countDown();

        } catch (SQLException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }

    });

} // ~ for ~

es.shutdown();

kickoffLatch.countDown();

taskCountDown.await();

log.info("It takes {} milliseconds to complete all {} tasks for {} insertions each. ",
        (System.currentTimeMillis()-start), nCore, batchPerCore);
```

as it proceeded, it shows 3 tasks completed running the courses at 2:09 PM, but others still pending as of this writing (3:29PM).

Here is the log:

```
Apr 27, 2020 1:25:17 PM com.db.loader.DBFlexDataLoadingPerfTest lambda$4
INFO: Thread pool-1-thread-7 starts working on 100000 insertion jobs.
Apr 27, 2020 1:25:17 PM com.db.loader.DBFlexDataLoadingPerfTest lambda$4
INFO: Thread pool-1-thread-2 starts working on 100000 insertion jobs.
Apr 27, 2020 1:25:17 PM com.db.loader.DBFlexDataLoadingPerfTest lambda$4
INFO: Thread pool-1-thread-5 starts working on 100000 insertion jobs.
Apr 27, 2020 1:25:17 PM com.db.loader.DBFlexDataLoadingPerfTest lambda$4
INFO: Thread pool-1-thread-8 starts working on 100000 insertion jobs.
Apr 27, 2020 1:25:17 PM com.db.loader.DBFlexDataLoadingPerfTest lambda$4
INFO: Thread pool-1-thread-4 starts working on 100000 insertion jobs.
Apr 27, 2020 1:25:17 PM com.db.loader.DBFlexDataLoadingPerfTest lambda$4
INFO: Thread pool-1-thread-3 starts working on 100000 insertion jobs.
Apr 27, 2020 1:25:17 PM com.db.loader.DBFlexDataLoadingPerfTest lambda$4
INFO: Thread pool-1-thread-6 starts working on 100000 insertion jobs.
Apr 27, 2020 1:25:17 PM com.db.loader.DBFlexDataLoadingPerfTest lambda$4
INFO: Thread pool-1-thread-1 starts working on 100000 insertion jobs.
Apr 27, 2020 2:09:53 PM com.db.loader.DBFlexDataLoadingPerfTest lambda$4
INFO: Thread pool-1-thread-4 completed its job!
Apr 27, 2020 2:09:53 PM com.db.loader.DBFlexDataLoadingPerfTest lambda$4
INFO: Thread pool-1-thread-6 completed its job!
Apr 27, 2020 2:09:53 PM com.db.loader.DBFlexDataLoadingPerfTest lambda$4
INFO: Thread pool-1-thread-7 completed its job!
```

Using DriverManager in this case is not a good idea, I should have used a DataSource implementation, nevertheless it is not relevant or affecting the purpose of this test.

Given that all tasks are the same in terms of the nature of the job and running fashion, I can't get it why some are seriously behind others, and more likely they are just hanging there.

No particular JVM arguments were set. The machine is Windows 10 pro, with a 8-core i7-6700 and 32G RAM.

Comment: You might want to consider executing smaller batches and - depending on the type of data - committing after each batch. Right now you are creating eight huge batches of 100,000 statements each and only executing at the end. Executing in smaller batches would more likely spread the load, and reduce memory consumption significantly.

Answer (score 0):

Threads are undeterministic. It is not guaranteed tha all tasks will be execyted evenly by all threads. In most pesimistic scenario those could be even serialized (not likely but not impossible). It is all in discretion of JVM implementation and OS scheduler.

Besides that there can be multiple implementation dependent factors that are not visible in provided code snippet (eg driver or db handling of parallel batches submition)